# PHP sort array()

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sql-order-by

I have an array which looks like:

```
array(
    'parent1' => array(
        name = 'somename',
        childs = array('child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4')
    ),
    'parent2' => array(
        name = 'somename',
        childs = array('child1')
    ),
    'parent3' => array(
        name = 'somename',
        childs = array('child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4', 'child5')
    )
    'parent4' => array(
        name = 'somename',
        childs = array('child1', 'child2', 'child3')
    ),
    'parent5' => array(
        name = 'somename',
        childs = array('child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4', 'child5', 'child6', 'child7')
    )
)
```

**Ho do I sort parents by its childs count (asc order)?** Parents and childs names should not be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function count_sort($a, $b) {
  if (count($a) == count($b)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (count($a) < count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

$test_array = array(
  'parent1' => array('child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4'),
  'parent2' => array('child1'),
  'parent3' => array('child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4', 'child5'),
  'parent4' => array('child1', 'child2', 'child3'),
  'parent5' => array('child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4', 'child5', 'child6', 'child7')
);

print_r($test_array);
usort($test_array, "count_sort");
print_r($test_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (count($a) == count($b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (count($a) < count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}


uksort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: Steve, if you ask a question, expect responses to it.  When you update your question so that it's completely different from the original, it isn't fair to the people who expended effort to give you ultra-fast answers to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [uasort](https://www.php.net/uasort) - it sorts the array **and** maintains key asscociations (so you won't lose your keys)

```
uasort($myArray, 'countSort');

function countSort($a, $b) {
    if (count($a['childs']) == count($b['childs'])) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return (count($a['childs']) < count($b['childs'])) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `uksort`:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return count($a) - count($b);
}

uksort($yourArray, "cmp");
```

---

To answer the updated question, you would use `uasort()` as **`@fin1te`** mentioned.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return count($a['childs']) - count($b['childs']);
}

uasort($yourArray, "cmp");
```