# Sort static array php

Tags: laravel

I want to sort this array alphabetically .I am defining my array here.I am calling it in foreach loop
    **Here is my code:**

```
private static $table_prefixes = [
        'alio',
        'dan_travel',
        'goway_ca',
        'goway_us',
        'picasso',
        'transam'
];

  public $suppliers_overview = [];
 public static function getTablePrefixes()
    {
        return self::$table_prefixes;
    }

 foreach (self::getTablePrefixes() as $prefix) {

            $this->suppliers_overview[$prefix]['name'] =$prefix;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP sort array()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380106/php-sort-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in place of your foreach

```
$this->suppliers_overview[] = array_sort_recursive(self::getTablePrefixes());
```